# WPF Design-Time Type-Cast error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Settings class, with a Singleton pattern:

```
public class Settings
{
    public static Settings Instance 
    {
         get { ... /* Return instance created by custom xml deserializer*/ }
    } 
    public Settings() 
    {
        /* Constructor used by custom xml deserializer */
    }

    public bool EnableImages { get; set; }
    public bool CheckForUpdates { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FavShowData> TvShows {get; set;}
    //....
}
```

In my Settings Form I bind to those settings:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckForUpdates, Source={x:Static local:Settings.Instance}}"  Content="Autocheck at start and every 30 minutes" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding EnableImages, Source={x:Static local:Settings.Instance}}"  Content="Enable Images" />
```

For both lines I'm getting the following design-time error:

> Das Objekt mit dem Typ
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[SjUpdater.Model.FavShowData]"
>   kann nicht in den Typ
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[SjUpdater.Model.FavShowData]"
>   konvertiert werden.

Translated:

> Object of type
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[SjUpdater.Model.FavShowData]"
>   can not be converted into type 
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[SjUpdater.Model.FavShowData]"

This is very strange, since I never bind to the *TvShows* Property.
Compilation is fine and the code works as desired.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that design-time error?

Comment: Dreamcooled: if you get such error, try switching to English language, or try to translate it. As of right now, he error does not tell anything, to most of the users. It might not have to do with the bindings, but the fact that you do some stuff inside constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: Move the Stuff to the ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Settings Settings
    {
        get { return Settings.Instance; }
    }
    //....
}
```

And change the XAML to:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Settings}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckForUpdates}"  Content="Autocheck at start and every 30 minutes" />
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding EnableImages}"  Content="Enable Images" />
    ....
</Grid>
```

No more Design-Time Errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the properties as static too... You are working a static class which doesn't allow an instance constructor, yet your properties are not identified as static either

```
public static bool EnableImages { get; set; }
public static bool CheckForUpdates { get; set; }
public static ObservableCollection<FavShowData> TvShows {get; set;}
```

Comment: I have to use the singleton pattern and can't make the properties static because I use a custom XmlSerializer. I modified the code in the question accordingly.